# View with continuous scroll; both horizontal and vertical

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, infinite-scroll

I have been struggling with this assignment for quite some time now. What I would like to develop is a scrollview or collectionview which scrolls continuously both vertical and horizontal.

Here is an image of how I think this should look like. The transparent boxes are the views/cells which are re-loaded from the memory. As soon as a view/cell gets outside of the screen, it should be reused for upcoming new cell.. just like how a `UITableViewController` works.

[image: Continuous scroll]

I know that a `UICollectionView` can only be made to infinite scroll horizontal OR vertical, not both. However, I don't know how to do this using a `UIScrollView`.
I tried the code [attached to an answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13700334/406677) and I can get it to re-create views (e.g. % 20) but that's not really what I need.. besides, its not continuous.

I know it is possible, because the HBO Go app does this.. I want exactly the same functionality.

My Question: How can I achieve my goal? Are there any guides/tutorials that can show me how? I can't find any.

Comment: Whats the plan for reusability ? I mean, are those tiles going to be the same or repeated images (just maybe different number labels) ? This is the hard part, the scrolling part should be straightforward.

Comment: The tiles are the same. E.g. if tile 1 would be an image of a red rose, next time tile 1 is shown it will be the exact same rose. Exactly the same as with the `HBO GO` app. Basically it should load the tiles from an NSArray with UIViews or UIButtons or similar.

It should be straightforward, however I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Do you really need it to be infinite? I've done this with a collection view that repeats 20 cells (4 rows of 5 items like in your example), but if I make it appear to have more than about a 1000 rows in each direction, the scrolling becomes jerky. But even with 1000 in each direction, it seems pretty infinite.

Comment: @rdelmar what do you mean by "jerky"? Do you mean that it gets slow?

Comment: Not slow if you're panning, but if you do swipes, it goes fast then pauses then resumes. With 1000 cells or less, I don't really notice this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get infinite scrolling, by using the technique of re-centering the `UIScrollView` after you get a certain distance away from the center. First, you need to make the `contentSize` big enough that you can scroll a bit, so I return 4 times the number of items in my sections and 4 times the number of sections, and use the mod operator in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method to get the right index into my array. You then have to override `layoutSubviews` in a subclass of `UICollectionView` to do the re-centering (this is demonstrated in the WWDC 2011 video, "Advanced Scroll View Techniques"). Here is the controller class that has the collection view (set up in IB) as a subview:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MultpleLineLayout.h"
#import "DataCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *theData;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.theData = @[@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5"], @[@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10"],@[@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15"],@[@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20"]];
    MultpleLineLayout *layout = [[MultpleLineLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[DataCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DataCell"];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 16;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DataCell *cell = [collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DataCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = self.theData[indexPath.section %4][indexPath.row %5];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // UICollectionViewCell *item = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);

}
```

Here is the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass:

```
#define space 5
#import "MultpleLineLayout.h"

@implementation MultpleLineLayout { // a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    NSInteger itemWidth;
    NSInteger itemHeight;
}

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        itemWidth = 60;
        itemHeight = 60;
    }
    return self;
}

-(CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    NSInteger xSize = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0] * (itemWidth + space); // "space" is for spacing between cells.
    NSInteger ySize = [self.collectionView numberOfSections] * (itemHeight + space);
    return CGSizeMake(xSize, ySize);
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];
    attributes.size = CGSizeMake(itemWidth,itemHeight);
    int xValue = itemWidth/2 + path.row * (itemWidth + space);
    int yValue = itemHeight + path.section * (itemHeight + space);
    attributes.center = CGPointMake(xValue, yValue);
    return attributes;
}


-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSInteger minRow =  (rect.origin.x > 0)?  rect.origin.x/(itemWidth + space) : 0; // need to check because bounce gives negative values  for x.
    NSInteger maxRow = rect.size.width/(itemWidth + space) + minRow;
    NSMutableArray* attributes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSInteger i=0 ; i < self.collectionView.numberOfSections; i++) {
        for (NSInteger j=minRow ; j < maxRow; j++) {
            NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:j inSection:i];
            [attributes addObject:[self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        }
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

And finally, here is the subclass of `UICollectionView`:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGPoint currentOffset = self.contentOffset;
    CGFloat contentWidth = self.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat contentHeight = self.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat centerOffsetX = (contentWidth - self.bounds.size.width)/ 2.0;
    CGFloat centerOffsetY = (contentHeight - self.bounds.size.height)/ 2.0;
    CGFloat distanceFromCenterX = fabsf(currentOffset.x - centerOffsetX);
    CGFloat distanceFromCenterY = fabsf(currentOffset.y - centerOffsetY);

    if (distanceFromCenterX > contentWidth/4.0) { // this number of 4.0 is arbitrary
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(centerOffsetX, currentOffset.y);
    }
    if (distanceFromCenterY > contentHeight/4.0) {
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(currentOffset.x, centerOffsetY);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement your code. I get a `gridLayout` but inserting the method `layoutSubviews` causes my view to repeat always the same. I also get sometimes the exception `[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]` after scrolling a little bit. does somebody of you have some more input how to get it work?

Answer (score 9):

@updated for swift 3 and changed how the maxRow is calculated otherwise the last column is cutoff and can cause errors

```
import UIKit

class NodeMap : UICollectionViewController {
    var rows = 10
    var cols = 10

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = NodeLayout(itemWidth: 400.0, itemHeight: 300.0, space: 5.0)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rows
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return cols
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "node", for: indexPath)
    }
}

class NodeLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var itemWidth : CGFloat
    var itemHeight : CGFloat
    var space : CGFloat
    var columns: Int{
        return self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
    }
    var rows: Int{
        return self.collectionView!.numberOfSections
    }

    init(itemWidth: CGFloat, itemHeight: CGFloat, space: CGFloat) {
        self.itemWidth = itemWidth
        self.itemHeight = itemHeight
        self.space = space
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.itemWidth = 50
        self.itemHeight = 50
        self.space = 3
        super.init()
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize{
        let w : CGFloat = CGFloat(columns) * (itemWidth + space)
        let h : CGFloat = CGFloat(rows) * (itemHeight + space)
        return CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        let x : CGFloat = CGFloat(indexPath.row) * (itemWidth + space)
        let y : CGFloat = CGFloat(indexPath.section) + CGFloat(indexPath.section) * (itemHeight + space)
        attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        return attributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let minRow : Int = (rect.origin.x > 0) ? Int(floor(rect.origin.x/(itemWidth + space))) : 0
        let maxRow : Int = min(columns - 1, Int(ceil(rect.size.width / (itemWidth + space)) + CGFloat(minRow)))
        var attributes : Array<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes> = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        for i in 0 ..< rows {
            for j in minRow ... maxRow {
                attributes.append(self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: j, section: i))!)
            }
        }
        return attributes
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the issue with spacing. I tried to set it to 0 and there was still a small line in between each row. To remove this change this line to `let y : CGFloat = CGFloat(indexPath.section) * (itemHeight + space)`. He was adding the index twice

Answer (score 2):

@rdelmar's answer worked like a charm, but I needed to do it in swift.  Here's the conversion :)

```
class NodeMap : UICollectionViewController {
    @IBOutlet var activateNodeButton : UIBarButtonItem?
    var rows = 10
    var cols = 10
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rows
    }
    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return cols
    }
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("node", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = NodeLayout(itemWidth: 100.0, itemHeight: 100.0, space: 5.0)
    }
}

class NodeLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var itemWidth : CGFloat
    var itemHeight : CGFloat
    var space : CGFloat
    init(itemWidth: CGFloat, itemHeight: CGFloat, space: CGFloat) {
        self.itemWidth = itemWidth
        self.itemHeight = itemHeight
        self.space = space
        super.init()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.itemWidth = 50
        self.itemHeight = 50
        self.space = 3
        super.init()
    }
    override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        let w : CGFloat = CGFloat(self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0)) * (itemWidth + space)
        let h : CGFloat = CGFloat(self.collectionView!.numberOfSections()) * (itemHeight + space)
        return CGSizeMake(w, h)
    }
    override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
        let x : CGFloat = CGFloat(indexPath.row) * (itemWidth + space)
        let y : CGFloat = CGFloat(indexPath.section) + CGFloat(indexPath.section) * (itemHeight + space)
        attributes.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, itemWidth, itemHeight)
        return attributes
    }
    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
        let minRow : Int = (rect.origin.x > 0) ? Int(floor(rect.origin.x/(itemWidth + space))) : 0
        let maxRow : Int = Int(floor(rect.size.width/(itemWidth + space)) + CGFloat(minRow))
        var attributes : Array<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes> = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        for i in 0...self.collectionView!.numberOfSections()-1 {
            for j in minRow...maxRow {
                attributes.append(self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: j, inSection: i)))
            }
        }
        return attributes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Resetting the contentOffset probably is the best solution figured out so far.
[image: infinite scrolling final result]

A few steps should be taken to achieve this:

1. Pad extra items at both the left and right side of the original data set to achieve larger scrollable area; This is similar to having a large duplicated data set, but difference is the amount;
2. At start, the collection view’s contentOffset is calculated to show only the original data set (drawn in black rectangles);
3. When the user scrolls right and contentOffset hits the trigger value, we reset contentOffset to show same visual results; but actually different data; When the user scrolls left, the same logic is used.

[image]

So, the heavy lifting is in calculating how many items should be padded both on the left and right side. If you take a look at the illustration, you will find that a minimum of one extra screen of items should be padded on left and also, another extra screen on the right. The exact amount padded depends on how many items are in the original data set and how large your item size is.

I wrote a post on this solution:

https://github.com/Alex1989Wang/Blogs/blob/master/contents/2018-03-24-Infinite-Scrolling-and-the-Tiling-Logic.md