# Instead of UICollectionView a black screen is displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uicollectionview, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to reimplement the infinitive scrolling `UICollectionView` seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553973/426227). Things that were missing for me:

*ViewController.h*:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@end
```

*DataCell.h*:

```
@interface DataCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;
@end
```

*DataCell.m*:

```
#import "DataCell.h"

@implementation DataCell

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        self.label.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
        self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

        [self addSubview:self.label];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

*CustomCollectionView.h:*

```
@interface CustomCollectionView : UICollectionView

@end
```

For the whole project I used a storyboard and a normal `UIViewController`. On this view controller I added a `UICollectionView` in Interface Builder. I connected the outlet from the collection view with my view controller and set up the datasource and delegate methods again to my view controller. I also set the custom class of the `UICollectionViewCell` and the reuse identifier in Interface Builder.

So everything should work but I only get a black screen. What I'm missing? You can download the whole project [here](http://www4.zippyshare.com/v/Uo6AybNY/file.html).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are configuring correctly the CollectionView, just that you forgot the color of the label :)

```
    [self.label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

You need to manually set the background color of the collection view in the storyboard.

By default it is black (although not showing that in the storyboard editor)

[image]

Comment: if you want the background to be clear, you have to use `collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` and `collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. The black screen seems to be an indicator of no data available with collection view to display. Try changing the background color of the collection view, if that changed color got to display, your collection view is working. And then add some imageview to the collection view with tag (Ex. give a value 100 with the tag value for the image view) and with the cellforItemAtIndexPath set the images to the image view.
(You can do this with custom cell. But for now, to get the collection view work, the assignment with tag for the imageview suits better)

```
UIImageView * ImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProductCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ProductCollectionViewCell"];

self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

it happened to me that both the collectionView and the collection view cell had transparent backgrounds

Answer (score 1):

In Swift,

```
self.label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```