# Collection View Header not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am currently implementing infinite scrolling using `collectionView` by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549233/view-with-continuous-scroll-both-horizontal-and-vertical/27770949#comment82218252_27770949). But I got stuck when I have to add `collectionView` `sectionheader`. The header doesn't shows up when I am implemeting the above link custom flow layout, but if I use default `UICollectionViewLayout` it's been displayed.

Implemented the method : -

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
```

Comment: Have you implemented `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` for the delegate? It won't show sections if you don't declare them.

Comment: @TristanWarner-Smith  I have implemented it. Moreover I have written that it's showing header in case of default `UICollectionViewLayout`

Comment: Have you registered the section header as a xib and implemented viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind?

Comment: @TristanWarner-Smith registered it

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
```

This function is important for giving the size for collection view section header , and if you using the UICollectionViewLayout functions and pass the attribute layout then "referenceSizeForHeaderInSection"  method is not need to implement

```
layoutAttributesForElements(in rect:)
```

Comment: which method you are using "referenceSizeForHeaderInSection" or "layoutAttributesForElements".

Comment: Can you show me how to you registered the section. and i aman19ish@gmail.com

Comment: This answer actually helped me get unstuck from an issue I was having where I was already recalculating the header frame in my flowlayout subclass.
Unfortunately I can't upvote it because I think it needs to be improved and expanded on for clarity in order to answer the original question. I'm not sure most people want to be touching something like `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect:)`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion bitwit

Answer (score 0):

It works for me please try it hope helps to you

Set the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate

```
YourViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

if You want scrolling then you can use this method in didLoad method

```
self.yourcollectionview.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal

self.yourcollectionview.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical
```

Comment: have you used the same link for both side scrolling ?

Comment: Will You want scrolling ? ( vertically or horizontally)

Comment: I want both way