# 2-way scrolling Table in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, horizontal-scrolling

I am an android application developer and new to iOS programming and my very first challenge is to build a 2-way scrolling table in iOS. I am getting many solutions with UICollectionView inside UITableView. But in my case rows will scroll together, not independent of each other. There are more than 15 columns and 100+ rows with text data in the table.

I have achieved the same in Android by using a ListView inside a HorizontalScrollView. But yet to find any solution in iOS. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have added a couple of screens of the android app where the table is scrolled horizontally.

[image: This is starting position]

[image: This is after scrolling horizontally]

Comment: You can scroll 2 ways already... up... and down...  What you need is not a `UITableView` with `UICollectionViews` in the cells. What you need is just a `UICollectionView`. A collection view can have any layout you want. And what you want is fairly straight forward with a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549233/view-with-continuous-scroll-both-horizontal-and-vertical

Comment: @Marty The detail provided by you seems incomplete, you should provide more details with screens if possible

Comment: @Satish I have now added two screenshots showing horizontal scrolling of the table. This is from the android app that i have made.

Comment: @Marty
Add your `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`. Add constraints to `UIScrollView`.
Now add `UITableView` top, trailing, bottom, leading constraint with `UIScrollView`. Also, add UITableVIew height constraint equal to `UIScrollView` and `UITableView` width constraint equal to your `UITableView` row width.

You can achieve this using `UICollectionView` as mentioned above.

Comment: @Satish will definitely try both options.

Answer (score 3):

So you want this:

[image: demo]

You should use a `UICollectionView`. You can't use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (the only layout that's provided in the public SDK) because it is designed to only scroll in one direction, so you need to implement a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass that arranges the elements to scroll in both directions if needed.

For full details on building a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass, you should watch these: videos from WWDC 2012:

- [Session 205: Introducing Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/205/)
- [Session 219: Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/219/)

Anyway, I'll just dump an example implementation of `GridLayout` here for you to start with. For each `IndexPath`, I use the `section` as the row number and the `item` as the column number.

```
class GridLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    var cellHeight: CGFloat = 22
    var cellWidths: [CGFloat] = [] {
        didSet {
            precondition(cellWidths.filter({ $0 <= 0 }).isEmpty)
            invalidateCache()
        }
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: totalWidth, height: totalHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        // When bouncing, rect's origin can have a negative x or y, which is bad.
        let newRect = rect.intersection(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: totalWidth, height: totalHeight))

        var poses = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        let rows = rowsOverlapping(newRect)
        let columns = columnsOverlapping(newRect)
        for row in rows {
            for column in columns {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: column, section: row)
                poses.append(pose(forCellAt: indexPath))
            }
        }

        return poses
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return pose(forCellAt: indexPath)
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    private struct CellSpan {
        var minX: CGFloat
        var maxX: CGFloat
    }

    private struct Cache {
        var cellSpans: [CellSpan]
        var totalWidth: CGFloat
    }

    private var _cache: Cache? = nil
    private var cache: Cache {
        if let cache = _cache { return cache }
        var spans = [CellSpan]()
        var x: CGFloat = 0
        for width in cellWidths {
            spans.append(CellSpan(minX: x, maxX: x + width))
            x += width
        }
        let cache = Cache(cellSpans: spans, totalWidth: x)
        _cache = cache
        return cache
    }

    private var totalWidth: CGFloat { return cache.totalWidth }
    private var cellSpans: [CellSpan] { return cache.cellSpans }

    private var totalHeight: CGFloat {
        return cellHeight * CGFloat(collectionView?.numberOfSections ?? 0)
    }

    private func invalidateCache() {
        _cache = nil
        invalidateLayout()
    }

    private func rowsOverlapping(_ rect: CGRect) -> Range<Int> {
        let startRow = Int(floor(rect.minY / cellHeight))
        let endRow = Int(ceil(rect.maxY / cellHeight))
        return startRow ..< endRow
    }

    private func columnsOverlapping(_ rect: CGRect) -> Range<Int> {
        let minX = rect.minX
        let maxX = rect.maxX
        if let start = cellSpans.firstIndex(where: { $0.maxX >= minX }), let end = cellSpans.lastIndex(where: { $0.minX <= maxX }) {
            return start ..< end + 1
        } else {
            return 0 ..< 0
        }
    }

    private func pose(forCellAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        let pose = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.section
        let column = indexPath.item
        pose.frame = CGRect(x: cellSpans[column].minX, y: CGFloat(row) * cellHeight, width: cellWidths[column], height: cellHeight)
        return pose
    }
}
```

To draw the separating lines, I added hairline views to each cell's background:

```
class GridCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String { return "cell" }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        label.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: 2, dy: 2)
        label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.addSubview(label)

        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: frame.size))
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.backgroundView = backgroundView

        rightSeparator.backgroundColor = .gray
        backgroundView.addSubview(rightSeparator)

        bottomSeparator.backgroundColor = .gray
        backgroundView.addSubview(bottomSeparator)
    }

    func setRecord(_ record: String) {
        label.text = record
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let thickness = 1 / (window?.screen.scale ?? 1)
        let size = bounds.size
        rightSeparator.frame = CGRect(x: size.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: size.height)
        bottomSeparator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: size.height - thickness, width: size.width, height: thickness)
    }

    private let label = UILabel()
    private let rightSeparator = UIView()
    private let bottomSeparator = UIView()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here's my demo view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var records: [[String]] = (0 ..< 20).map { row in
        (0 ..< 6).map {
            column in
            "Row \(row) column \(column)"
        }
    }

    var cellWidths: [CGFloat] = [ 180, 200, 180, 160, 200, 200 ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout = GridLayout()
        layout.cellHeight = 44
        layout.cellWidths = cellWidths
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.register(GridCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: GridCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return records.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return records[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: GridCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GridCell
        cell.setRecord(records[indexPath.section][indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try. For now its a little overwhelming. Thank you :)

Comment: @Marty this is what I was saying in my comment... but a little more complete than my comment. Haha. What you are creating is something like a spreadsheet so it can seem overwhelming but if you organise your data in a nice way then it shouldn't be too hard to create. To start with just create the view with some dummy data in it. Hopefully that will help you create the view without having to think about the data. Then you can start putting the real data in and making the cells display what you want.

Comment: 'Tis not the data that overwhelms me @Fogmeister haha, it's the code. Yeah I get your point. I do have a sample JSON with sufficient data. But will start off with some even simpler format. Somehow had much less hassle to deal with in Android. But maybe that's me being noob is all.